# Is it possible to avoid entering the folder after selecting a folder for upload

Tags: javascript, html, file, web, directory

I wonder folder upload button behaviour.

If you choose a folder for uploading with this button and then try it again you we'll appear in the wrong location of folder select dialog.

Is it possible to avoid falling into the folder after you select it for the last time.
It is a real inconvenient browser behaviour.

My OS is Windows.

I need it for a real project.

You can try here
[example to test](https://codepen.io/PavelOfficial/pen/OJEBBzV)

Here an example of button that selects a directory:

```
<div>
  <input type="file" directory webkitdirectory />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Regretfully, you can not do that.